# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null" error in my console? I am using google chrome if that helps at all. The javascript section is at the bottom of the html document.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Drum_Kit.css">
    </head>
    <body>


      <div class="keys">
        <div data-key="65" class="key">
          <kbd>A</kbd>
          <span class="sound">clap</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="83" class="key">
          <kbd>S</kbd>
          <span class="sound">hihat</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="68" class="key">
          <kbd>D</kbd>
          <span class="sound">kick</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="70" class="key">
          <kbd>F</kbd>
          <span class="sound">openhat</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="71" class="key">
          <kbd>G</kbd>
          <span class="sound">boom</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="72" class="key">
          <kbd>H</kbd>
          <span class="sound">ride</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="74" class="key">
          <kbd>J</kbd>
          <span class="sound">snare</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="75" class="key">
          <kbd>K</kbd>
          <span class="sound">tom</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="76" class="key">
          <kbd>L</kbd>
          <span class="sound">tink</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <audio data-key="65" src="Crash-Cymbal-1.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="83" src="holy_hole.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="68" src="holy_heart_failure.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="70" src="holy_fruit_salad.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="71" src="holy_mashed_potatoes.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="72" src="holy_nightmare.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="74" src="holy_las_vegas.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="75" src="holy_caffeine.wav"></audio>
      <audio data-key="76" src="holy_alphabet.wav"></audio>

    <script>

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
      const audio = document.querySelector("audio[data-key = '${e.keyCode}']");
        if(!audio) console.log("this is not working");
        audio.play();

    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is the element with `data-key='${e.keyCode}'`? Perhaps you meant `"audio[data-key='" + ${e.keyCode} + "']"`

Comment: @RobG after trying it your way I received the error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. I played around with the order of the quotes seeing how there seems to be the right amount of ) with your and my original way but continued to get either the "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error or the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null"  error.

Comment: @RobG Do you think something could be wrong with the audio files I am using?

Comment: You probably want `"audio[data-key='" + $(e.keyCode) + "']"`, i.e. with `( )` not `{ }`, but *$* isn't needed at all. Make sure all your quotes are quotes and there aren't any hidden characters. I prefer to use single quotes for script and double for HTML, so `'audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]'`.

Comment: Okay great that worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no spacing in the selector portion or the desired element will not be found. You also did not use the right type of quotes for the ES6 reference you made; thus, `${e.keyCode}` becomes processed as a string instead of a variable. You will want to use ` instead of " in this situation.

Current format:

```
const audio = document.querySelector("audio[data-key = '${e.keyCode}']");
```

Resolved format:

```
const audio = document.querySelector(\`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]\`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better approach [this approach will work on Firefox and IE9+] you'll need to check with chrome for [event].key support.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Drum_Kit.css">
    </head>
    <body>


      <div class="keys">
        <div data-key="65" class="key">
          <kbd>A</kbd>
          <span class="sound">clap</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="83" class="key">
          <kbd>S</kbd>
          <span class="sound">hihat</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="68" class="key">
          <kbd>D</kbd>
          <span class="sound">kick</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="70" class="key">
          <kbd>F</kbd>
          <span class="sound">openhat</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="71" class="key">
          <kbd>G</kbd>
          <span class="sound">boom</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="72" class="key">
          <kbd>H</kbd>
          <span class="sound">ride</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="74" class="key">
          <kbd>J</kbd>
          <span class="sound">snare</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="75" class="key">
          <kbd>K</kbd>
          <span class="sound">tom</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="76" class="key">
          <kbd>L</kbd>
          <span class="sound">tink</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <audio id=a src="Crash-Cymbal-1.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=s src="holy_hole.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=d src="holy_heart_failure.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=f src="holy_fruit_salad.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=g src="holy_mashed_potatoes.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=h src="holy_nightmare.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=j src="holy_las_vegas.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=k src="holy_caffeine.wav"></audio>
      <audio id=l src="holy_alphabet.wav"></audio>

    <script>

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        this[e.key] ? this[e.key].play() : 0;
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```