# Can not read property 'play' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-audio

So, what i'm trying to do is create a custom audio player. Simple enough right? That's what I thought, but then I'm getting this error "can not read property 'play' of null". I was reading about it, and I learned that one of the possibilities could be that the function is being called before the ID exist? but to me, that doesn't make sense since when a person clicks play, the property does exist. I've never created a custom audio player before so I could be way wrong here, but I would like to know how I can get this working. I'd like to play a song at the click of a button. Here is what I have so far

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";
  audioPlayer = <HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById("myAudio");

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInIt() {}

  start() {
    this.audioPlayer.play();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center mb-3">
      <img src="../assets/tour.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
      <p class="audio-title">Dark Queen - Lil Uzi vert</p>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="play" (click)="start()">play</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="pause">pause</button>
      <audio id="myAudio" class="audio" controls>
        <source src="../assets/darkqueen.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411691/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-play-of-null) this is the only other SO discussion I found but honestly it's different from what i'm facing.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: move `audioPlayer = <HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById("myAudio");` into onInit otherwise the method will run before the DOM even exists

Comment: try moving the `audioPlayer = <HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById("myAudio");` inside `ngOnInit`

Comment: @JijoCleetus #first :3  ^^

Comment: Understanding the error is crucial here: it simply means that when `this.audioPlayer.play();` is called, `this.audioPlayer` is `null`. Also note the typo: `ngOnInIt` is supposed to be `ngOnInit`

Comment: @jonathanHeindl thanks but didn't work because I can't use audioplayer inside of the start function now

Comment: then keep the delcaration outSide and only assign in the onINit

Comment: @jonathanHeindl inside `ngOnInit` the template is not reachable yet. You are looking for the `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: @jonathanHeindl your solution worked by the way, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The template is available in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook. Not in the constructor or ngOnInit.

Better however would be to use `@ViewChild()`:

```
<audio class="audio" controls #myAudio>
  <source src="../assets/darkqueen.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('myAudio')
  audioPlayer?: ElementRef<HTMLMediaElement>;

  start() {
    if (this.audioPlayer) { // if statement needed for strict typescript
      this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.play();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, so for ElementRef do I just assign document.getElementById('myAudio') to it?

Comment: No, `@ViewChild('myAudio')` will look for an element in your template with a `#myAudio` attribute. So you need to add this to your template (as shown in my answer)

Comment: It's giving me an error 'cannot find name ElementRef'

Comment: @DreJackson You need to import this from `'@angular/core'`.